# Accents in the database

Tags: php, html, mysql, htmlspecialchars

I am creating a database with MySql. I use collation utf8. I use a European language that has accents and special characters like ç.

What is the best way to store text in the database, with or without special characters? For example, should I use différent or `diffdiff&eacute;rent` (different in French) in the database? (This means, I should convert with htmlspecialcharts before or after I store the text in the database?)

I tried and both ways work well. But is there any reason that makes an option more recommended for any technical reason or any option is ok. I want to be sure now that I begin the database. Later it will be harder to change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should definitely **NOT** replace your characters with HTML entities: that is a standard for XML, not for everything!

For instance, if you had to serve JSON for some reason, you would then be forced to XML-decode your text, then serve it as JSON, where UTF-8 characters are encoded in a different way.

Also, converting characters would make your stored strings much less human-readable (thus less human-searchable): `Le premier écoquartier d’Île-de-France a été inauguré` would be encoded into something absolutely devilish.

Let your MySQL do the hard job, taking care of non-ASCII characters.

Answer (score 2):

Two subjects here.

1. Is necessary/useful to restrict yourself to 7-bit US-ASCII in an application that's powered by UTF-8 and needs characters outside US-ASCII? It's certainly not necessary and I can't imagine a single reason to. It's like saving your videos as uncompressed WAV. In most contexts, 8 bits are here to stay.
2. Is necessary/useful to convert your plain text to HTML in order to store it? You obviously don't need to do it, I can't think of a single benefit and you force yourself into the additional burden of bogus encoding/decoding for any single task like e.g. searching. HTML is not everything.

Comment: Ok, I understand, but if html is not recommended in the database, how to store a text like a blog that needs titles?

Comment: Sorry if I somehow suggested that storing HTML in a database is strictly forbidden in all circumstances. You never said anything about blog contents in your question. If you need HTML you have to save HTML, that's pretty obvious. Imagine your question was whether you need to store text as image. Answer is clearly "no" but that doesn't mean you need a workaround to save your logos!

Comment: Just in case, let me also clarify what appears to be a common misconception: relational database servers don't care about the HTML language, it's meaningless for them. They only care about the SQL language. However, people is using `strip_tags()` and `htmlentities()` all the time to e.g. store passwords!